# Keep a parent process waiting and run linux command as many times as wanted

Tags: c, gcc, fork

I have the below C code in linux (using gcc):

```
void doWho(void)
{
        char entry[10];
        int ret, i;
        ret = read(0, entry, 10);
        if (*entry == 'u')
        {
                for(i=0; i<3; i++)
                {
                execl("/usr/bin/who","who",NULL);
                }
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int childpid;

        printf("Before it forks\n");
        childpid = fork();

        if(childpid == 0)
        {
                printf("This is a child process\n");
                doWho();
                exit(0);
        } else
        {
                printf("This is the parent process\n");
                wait(NULL);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I want the parent process to keep waiting indefinitely and run "who" every time I press the "u" key. I only get the desired effect one time and then the child and parent processes exit. Any help on this?

Comment: I think you need to [read more about the `exec` family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) and how they work. In short: The loop should be over the `fork` and `doWho`/`wait` calls.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with fork? You can also do it with a simple C program?

Comment: This is an assignment, my code would be required to create child processes to run a linux command every time I press a specific key

Comment: In an informal explanation: exec will transform the process in the one you specified, hence the for is no longer executed, because the process became a new one. To achieve what you want the for should be before the fork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe below loop :

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    execl("/usr/bin/who","who",NULL);
}
```

It doesn't matter how many times you rotate the loop , it will execute only `once` because when `child process` starts running(`PCB` created), you are calling function `doWho` then control will come to `doWho` function and in `doWho` function what you are doing ? `execl()`. what `execl()` does is that " it `replaces` current process(`child`) with `new` process, after when `i = 0` whole `child process image` got replaced with `new` one using `execl()`, so there is nothing left in child process that's why it will execute only once.

If you want to execute  as many as you should use `fork()` in the function because then `exec` will replace `every process created by fork()`, but it's not advised to run fork() in loop because your program may crash when there are no more resource available.

So replace your `doWho` function as

```
void doWho(void)
{
        char entry[10] = {0};
        int ret, i;

        for(; ;) {
        /** who command will be executed when ever condition is true **/
                ret = read(0, entry, 10);
                __fpurge(stdin);//to clear stdin buffer everytime 
                if (*entry == 'u') {

                        if(fork()==0)//only this newly created process will be replaces by execl not one was in main()
                                execl("/usr/bin/who","who",NULL);
                        else
                                ;// this parents does nothing   
                }
        }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly. _fpurge(stdin) is rejected by the compiler even when including stdio_ext.h, but I'll try a way around that.

Comment: yes fpurge() is nonstandard  and  not  portable as mentioned in man page. may be your compiler not supporting this.